# SwiftUI: Conditional Context Menu Shown Unexpectedly

Tags: swiftui, editmode

In the following SwiftUI view, why does the conditional `.contextMenu` not work correctly?

Steps:

1. Long press the list item
2. Tap Edit
3. Long press the list item again

On the second long press the context menu should not appear because `editMode?.wrappedValue` is `.active`. But it does appear. How to fix that?

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.editMode) private var editMode
    
    var body: some View {
        let contextMenu = ContextMenu {
            Button("Do nothing", action: {})
        }
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 12) {
            EditButton().padding()
            List {
                ForEach(1..<2) {i in
                    Text("Long press me. Editing: \((editMode?.wrappedValue == .active).description)")
                        .contextMenu(editMode?.wrappedValue == .active ? nil : contextMenu)
                }
                    .onDelete(perform: { _ in })
                    .onMove(perform: { _, _ in })
            }
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works fine with Xcode 14 / iOS 16

Here is possible workaround for older versions (it is possible to try different places for `.id` modifier to have appropriate, acceptable, UI feedback)

Tested with Xcode 13.4 / iOS 15.5

```
Text("Long press me. Editing: \((editMode?.wrappedValue == .active).description)")
    .contextMenu(editMode?.wrappedValue == .active ? nil : contextMenu)
    .id(editMode?.wrappedValue)    // << this !!
```

Comment: If I apply any transition, views disappear and appear in this method. Maybe this is because of the id() modifier.